# Create an array of the last 15 closes if the close is bigger than open

Tags: pine-script

I would like to create an array of the last 15 closes if the close is larger than the open. I looked at exhibitions, and they look complicated in pine script. Not sure why? Any help? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you find complicated about arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This code will scan the 15 lasts bars and store in an array the closes which are larger than the open :
closesArray = array.new_float(0)

```
for i = 0 to 14
    if close[i] > open[i]
        array.push(closesArray, close[i])
```